# найти одноцифровые числа в матрице и перемножить их

Tags: c++, функции

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;
/*Çàäàíèå 1: */
void prod(int a[5][3]){
    int p;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            if(a[i][j] < 10) p *= a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    srand(time(0));
    setlocale(0, "Rus");
    int i, j, p; 
    int a[5][3];
    
    
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            
            a[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            cout << a[i][j] << '\t';
            if(a[i][j] < 10) p *= a[i][j];
            
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "=====================================" << endl;
        
    prod(a);    
    cout << "Result: " <<  endl;
    
    system("pause>>void");
    return 0;
    
}
```

нужно сделать всё в функции, но почему-то не выводится.

Comment: Логично, что ничего не выводится. Куча ошибок. В функции prod() не проинициализирована переменая p, никуда не возвращается результат. И вообще вы ничего не выводите, кроме строки "Result: ". Это то, что сразу в глаза бросается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приветик, итак, во-первых, когда ищем произведение предварительно присваиваем ему значение 1 (аналогично для суммы присваиваем 0).
Во-вторых, `if(a[i][j] < 10) p *= a[i][j];` в данном случае не имеет смысла писать, так как тебе нужно обработка матрицы в функции.
В-третьих,
`prod(a);     cout << "Result: " <<  endl;`
у тебя функция типа void и она не возвращает никаких значений для вывода результата в главном коде, а значит нужно выводить в функции void или же сделать функцию int prod дабы она возвращала произведение и вывод результата происходил в главном теле программы.
Немного подкорректировала твой код, и вот результат:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

void prod(int a[5][3]) {
    int p = 1, con = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] < 10 and a[i][j] > -10) {
                p *= a[i][j];
                con++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (con == 0) cout << "There are no single digit elements.";

    cout << "=====================================" << endl;
    cout << "Result: " << p << endl;
}

int main() {

    srand(time(0));
    setlocale(0, "Rus");

    int i, j, p = 1;
    int a[5][3];

    cout << "Matrix:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 20;
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    prod(a);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

К слову, написано в Visual Studio 2019 , если у тебя версия другая подправь библиотеки.
Собственно, вывод программы таков:

```
Matrix:
35      31      44
7       55      0
79      7       28
67      50      59
76      19      19
=====================================
Result: 0
```